# How can I properly output in column using setw or tab?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

long long int factorial(long long int n)//Factorial Function
{
  return (n == 1 || n == 0) ? 1 : factorial(n - 1) * n;
}

int main()
{
    float summ=0;
    float x=0;
    cout<<"Enter x value: "<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    float prespecified_error=0;
    cout<<"Enter prespecified error: "<<endl;
    cin>>prespecified_error;
    float true_value=0;
    true_value=exp(-x);
    cout<<true_value<<endl;
    float approx_error=10000000;
    float true_error=10000000;
    int i=0;
    float prev_value=0;
    cout<<"Value"<<setw(10)<<right<<"True error"<<setw(10)<<right<<"Approximate error"<<endl;//Output is not columned.
    while((prespecified_error<=true_error) || (prespecified_error<=approx_error)){
    summ=summ+(pow(-1,i)*(pow(x,i)/factorial(i)));
    true_error=((true_value-summ)/true_value)*100;
    if(true_error<0){
        true_error=true_error*(-1);
        }
    approx_error=((summ-prev_value)/summ)*100;
    if(approx_error<0){
        approx_error=approx_error*(-1);
        }
    prev_value=summ;
    cout<<summ<<setw(10)<<right<<true_error<<setw(10)<<right<<approx_error<<endl;//Output is not columned.  
    i=i+1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:::

```
0.00673795
Value           True error          Approximate error
1           14741.3         100
-4          59465.3         125
8.5         126051          147.059
-12.3333            183143          168.919
13.7083         203350          189.97
-12.3333            183143          211.149
9.36806         138934          231.653
-6.13294            91120.8         252.75
3.55518         52663.6         272.507
-1.8271         27216.6         294.58
0.86404         12723.5         311.461
-0.359208           5431.12         340.54
0.150479            2133.3          338.71
-0.0455546          776.09          430.326
0.0244573           262.978         286.262
0.00111998          83.378          2083.73
0.00841288          24.8582         86.6873
0.00626791          6.97596         34.2215
0.00686374          1.86688         8.68077
0.00670694          0.460185            2.33782
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using any field-width control (i.e. no `setw()`) *before* outputting `summ`... after that you're at a variable offset in the line and it's too late to get the other fields to line up.  Just work through your output statements methodically, perhaps putting a `'|'` or other character in to show you how much right-hand-side padding was added by each part of the output so you can concentrate on getting those to line up first, then remove them after you've got the field widths right.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the parameter width of `summ`.

```
std::cout << std::right 
          << std::setw(10) << summ
          << std::setw(10) << true_error
          << std::setw(10) << approx_error << std::endl;
```

As a side note you only need to specify `std::right` once

Comment: Then how do I solve this:   cout<<"Value"<<setw(10)<<right<<"True error"<<setw(10)<<right<<"Approximate error"<<endl;

Comment: same. set the width of `Value` because sending it to the stream.